# How to keep two Git servers in sync?

Tags: git, bitbucket, gitolite

Currently I am using Gitolite (server 1) but I just installed Bitbucket (server 2). There is around 30+ developers using number of git repositories on Gitolite now. They need to be migrated to new server.

I already created all users and repositories from server 1 on server 2.
I would like to for a period of time to keep two Git servers in sync.

What is the best way to keep pushing every change from server 1 to server 2. Is it even a good idea? Is there a better way to do the migration?

The plan is to use any given repository only from one server only.

1. I will fist keep pushing changes from each repo from server 1 to server 2 using:

> ```
> git clone --bare gitbox:project/${REPO}.git
> cd $REPO.git
> git remote add bitbucket bitbucket:/project/${REPO}
> git push --all bitbucket
> git push --tags bitbu
> ```

2. Configure all CI tools to start using server 2 bu have developers using server 1.
3. Repository by repository tell all developers from given repository to switch to server 2. There is always only a few developers using given repository.

Comment: You're going to have to deal with merging across those two servers. You should seriously consider a cold cut, just move the repository to the new server and remove it from the old, moving all developers in one go. You're probably going to spend more time keeping those in sync than you will if you just migrate in one go.

Comment: Do you have any specific reason to keep both servers in place for a time ?

Comment: I am trying to minimize the downtime:time from asking everybody to stop coming to one server 1, changing all CI paths, stopping deployments to time when everybody can start communicating again. Most developers are non-git and most likely the git reconfiguration command will need to be run for them.

Comment: For the user, *git remote set-url* will be the only thing they have to do to change the server 1 to server 2. You should use the week end time to do the change when nobody is using it (unless you are a startup who work on the week end aswell). On your side you don't need a lot of time to export/import the repositories from one server to the other one. If you think you can't do that, i will prepare an answer to help you do what you want